# Google pagespeed insights is loading assets twice

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am trying to optimize a Wordpress site and I have a low speed index on Google: 60/100

If I check the speed insights I see that GPS is loading some assets twice in the above-the-fold optimization, even if these files are only loaded once in the source code.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsysblog.devsite.it%2Fit%2F&tab=desktop

How do I interpretate this result?

Is the speed score reliable in this case (regarding this subject)?

[google pagespeed insights load twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZwkc.jpg)

Comment: check header and footer you added double the time wp_head() or wp_footer()

Comment: Thanks but in source code I do not see them!

Comment: You can't see in source check your header.php and footer.php in current active theme.